# Why were some of my questions are not well received?

Tags: support

Recently I asked questions about how to overclock my GPU

- [How do we know that bios that's avaialable on the net is compatible with my GPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1194789/how-do-we-know-that-bios-thats-avaialable-on-the-net-is-compatible-with-my-gpu)
- [Is there a way to turn on asrock H81 Pro BTC without dummy HDMI or monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/1195300/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-asrock-h81-pro-btc-without-dummy-hdmi-or-monitor)
- [How to properly use wattman? What's the meaning of this feature?](https://superuser.com/questions/1195405/how-to-properly-use-wattman-whats-the-meaning-of-this-feature)

I wonder what's wrong with those questions?

Answer (score 6):

While your questions seem to have an overarching point and reason, they are often very short on details and expect the reader to have read all your previous recent questions in order to define exactly *why* you need a specific almost never used feature.  Your questions tend to be simultaneously too broad (no real details) *and* too specific (focused on one tiny aspect of a larger problem).

If you need a GPGPU card (that would work headless) then you should be buying one of those, and potentially using an operating system that is more suitable. Consumer cards are designed to work in very particular situations and if you head "off piste" then you have to expect to work around their design limitations. Windows 10 was also mainly intended for home and work computers where an external display is almost universally required or available.

You also have been asking a lot of questions that have slightly worrying ramifications. I was particularly concerned by [What is this number I saw on ATIwinflash?](https://superuser.com/questions/1194712/what-is-this-number-i-saw-on-atiwinflash) which suggested that you really had no idea what files you were downloading and flashing to your card or why it is important that you download the right VBIOS file for your graphics card. You should know what file you are downloading *before* you got to the stage of trying to decrypt some arcane part numbering system. You are effectively diagnosing a problem that you yourself created rather than trying to deal with a problem that other people may have had and be able to help with.

In a number of cases it appears that the problem is not with your computer hardware or software but with the specific things you have expected to "just work". As such it is difficult to explain in simple terms that you should stop doing random things until you know exactly why you should or shouldn't be doing them in the first place.

Comment: This pretty much, your questions are asked in such a way, the reader would have to do research in order to answer them because the questions themselves do not have the research results.  This means having to research multiple (complex) topics for a niche feature

Comment: @Ramhound Well, IMHO, it is not so much that the questions require research.  E.g. if someone were to ask “Why are my socks yellow?”, it would be expected that the asker proffer enough information to limit the range of the necessary research to the scope of the question and in such a way that does not require detective work on behalf of the asker.

Comment: @can-ned_food I have been able to answer all three examples by doing a Google search myself so it really is about the appropriate research being done.

Comment: @Ramhound Er, that's not what I meant.  The way your comment was phrased made it sound as though an answer shouldn't require research.  I was offering a better way to express one of the ways a question could be poorly formed as pertains to research — insofar as that research is expected of the answer, not the question.  I didn't know that you were talking about a question which lacked research that is expected prior to the asking and within the means of the asker — a misunderstanding partly due, I think, to the way the comment was phrased.

Comment: @can-ned_food - I should be able to read a question, and not only understand what the question is, but be able to answer it with a minimalist amount of research (in order to backup my answer).

Comment: There's a difference between having a question in your head and being able to express that question such that Google can return results relevant to your question and likely to drive you towards an answer. If OP googled but had trouble phrasing the search terms correctly, that's one thing, but if they didn't even Google, that's a different and more off-putting problem.